# Is there any way to use the mouse to drag/resize a canvas?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am using a canvas with an Expander embedded within it, so that when the expander is expanded, it will overlay the controls below.

```
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="99">
            <Border Width="450" BorderThickness="1">
                <Expander etc />
            </Border>
        </Canvas>
        <OtherControls Grid.Row="1"/> etc
```

Instead of setting the size of the canvas, is there a way to allow the user to drag size it instead?

Comment: But you're not setting the size of the canvas. Or did you mean "instead of setting the size of the Border"? But Canvases are only useful if you *want* explicit sizes -- if you don't want to set explicit sizes, you shouldn't be using a Canvas.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate on why you're using a Canvas. Based on what you describe, I see no reason why a Canvas would do you any good compared to, say, putting multiple controls in the same Grid.Row.

Comment: @Joe White Canvas has certain advantages when programmatically working with cooardinates. Say I can use `Canvas.GetTop(x)` which I can not use it with say a Grid.

Answer (score 0):

here's a thought: Put everything in the grid. Let the grid resize itself automatically, put canvas in the grid (make sure it takes up the whole grid) so that it will follow the parent's size:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Canvas Background="Transparent" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <Border Width="450" BorderThickness="1">
            <Expander etc />
    </Border>

    <OtherControls Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

not sure how relevant this might be, but check out this post. Maybe it'll give you some ideas (I wrote that 4 years ago, way too long to remember specifics, but code compiles and runs):

http://denismorozov.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-resize-wpf-controls-at-runtime.html